# Override class name for XmlSerialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I need to serialize IEnumerable. At the same time I want root node to be "Channels" and second level node - Channel (instead of ChannelConfiguration).

Here is my serializer definition:

```
_xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ChannelConfiguration>), new XmlRootAttribute("Channels"));
```

I have overriden root node by providing XmlRootAttribute but I haven't found an option to set Channel instead of ChannelConfiguration as second level node.

I know I can do it by introducing a wrapper for IEnumerable and using XmlArrayItem but I don't want to do it.

Comment: why don't you want to do the easy option? out of curiosity? (note also: using non-trivial constructors means you **must** cache the serializer, else you leak assemblies; the basic `XmlSerializer(Type)` constructor doesn't suffer this)

Comment: Are you the owner of class ChannelConfiguration, are you able to decorate it with attributes? If yes I have probably a solution.

Comment: @MarcGravell, may be you are right and I should use a wrapper

Comment: @achitaka-san, yes, I am an owner of this class

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like so:

```
XmlAttributeOverrides or = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
or.Add(typeof(ChannelConfiguration), new XmlAttributes
{
    XmlType = new XmlTypeAttribute("Channel")
});
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ChannelConfiguration>), or,
     Type.EmptyTypes, new XmlRootAttribute("Channels"), "");
xmlSerializer.Serialize(Console.Out,
     new List<ChannelConfiguration> { new ChannelConfiguration { } });
```

Note you **must** cache and re-use this serializer instance.

I will also say that I strongly recommend you use the "wrapper class" approach - simpler, no risk of assembly leakage, and IIRC it works on more platforms (pretty sure I've seen an edge-case where the above behaves differently on some implementations - SL or WP7 or something like that).

If you have access to the type `ChannelConfiguration`, you can also just use:

```
[XmlType("Channel")]
public class ChannelConfiguration
{...}

var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ChannelConfiguration>),
     new XmlRootAttribute("Channels"));
xmlSerializer.Serialize(Console.Out,
     new List<ChannelConfiguration> { new ChannelConfiguration { } });
```

Answer (score 15):

This should do the trick, if I remember correctly.

```
[XmlType("Channel")] 
public class ChannelConfiguration {

}
```

Comment: When the object is part of a List<myObjects>, XmlRoot doesn't work...but XmlType DOES.  This fixed my issue, Thanks @JordyLangen.